# When using SQL not in function in the where clause, the null values are not returning in the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a simple test table to explain my case. Both the columns are varchar type.

[image: My Test Table]

When I run the query `select * from test1 where TValue not in ('3','4')` it returns the following 3 values only.

[image: Result]

I am expecting it to return Sample6 value too. May I know why its returning only 3 values and what I need to do for it to return the Sample6 value too.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/handling-null-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the three-tiered logic inherent in SQL databases.

Any expression comparing a value against NULL returns a value of "unknown" -- which is distinct from a "true" or a "false" value.

```
  1 = 1           true
  1 = 0           false
  1 = NULL        undefined
  NULL = NULL     undefined (!)
```

Your query asks for records that meet the criterion "tvalue NOT IN (3, 4)".   This will return a dataset in which the matching criteria are met.    Since the NULL values comparisons do not return a "true" value (and not a "false" one, either), they are NOT included in your return set.

There are a couple workarounds for this behavior:   the first is to explicitly test for null:

```
 WHERE tvalue IS NULL OR tvalue NOT IN (3,4)
```

The other is to use COALESCE to eliminate NULL comparisons:

```
 WHERE COALESCE(tvalue, 0) NOT IN (3,4)
```

For large tables, the first approach is probably the most efficient:  comparing against an expression (i.e. the COALESCE expression) means that the expression has to be executed against every row in the underlying dataset.

Comment: Thank you ! It makes sense now.

Answer (score 5):

Because `NULL` doesn't work the same way as other value in "normal" comparisons like `=`, `<`, `IN`, etc, you need to use `NULL` logic as well:

```
WHERE TValue NOT IN (3,4)
   OR TValue IS NULL;
```

When comparing against a `NULL` using an expression like `WHERE YourColumn != 1`, where `YourColumn` has the value `NULL`, will result with the boolean expression returning `NULL`. The data engine will only return values where the boolean expressions return true, which `NULL` is not, and hence `NULL != 1` will not result in the row(s) being returned.

Comment: Worded that poorly @GordonLinoff, you're right. Will reword.

Comment: For NULL-checking expressions, the NULL check should go *first*, or short-circuit logic in expression evaluation may never get to the second statement.    SQL Server actually compensates for this (in this particular case), but most database engines do not.    So, the expression should instead read:  "WHEN TValue IS NULL OR TValue NOT IN (3,4)", or you could continue to have the same issue that the OP described.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM test1
WHERE ISNULL(TValue, '') NOT IN ('3', '4')
```

Comment: This will work, but will cause the query to become non-SARGable, which would have performance implications on larger, indexed, tables.